# How to add shapes in a jqgrid cell

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i have a jqgrid.I need to add a shape(like circle ) into jqgrid cell and fill that circle with color .

Comment: What have you tried? Share some of your code so we can see what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a custom html to the last column with `jqgrid`.Try this fiddle mate.. :)

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hjape83r/)

Comment: Thank you ,i am also need same type of code ,is it possible to change the backgroundcolor based on a color coming from database

Comment: yes.add an inline style to the html like `style='background:db_color_value;'`